# Customizing controller

Tags: java, struts2, struts

While reading Struts2 documentation, I encountered the passage as quoted below

> customizing controller - Struts 1 lets
>   to customize the request processor per
>   module, Struts 2 lets to customize the
>   request handling per action, if
>   desired.

What do the author exactly mean.  Simple examples in code form for the demonstration on both will be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

Example of customizing the request processor in Struts 1:

```
<controller processorClass="org.springframework.web.struts.DelegatingRequestProcessor"/>
```

This replaces the default Struts request processor with a Spring one, which matches mapped Struts actions with beans in the Spring context to perform dependency injection.

Example of delegating action handling in Struts 1:

```
<action-mappings>
    <action  path="/welcome" forward="/WEB-INF/pages/welcome.htm"/>
    <action  path="/searchEntry" forward="/WEB-INF/pages/search.jsp"/>
    <action  path="/searchSubmit" 
             type="org.springframework.web.struts.DelegatingActionProxy" 
             input="/searchEntry.do"
             validate="true"
             name="searchForm">
        <forward name="success" path="/WEB-INF/pages/detail.jsp"/>
        <forward name="failure" path="/WEB-INF/pages/search.jsp"/>
</action>
```

Here the action type is replaced with a Spring proxy class, which looks up a matching bean (by path) in the Spring context. The purpose of this is also to inject dependencies in Struts 1 actions. It is just another approach, giving more control to Spring.

I don't know how things work in Struts 2.